# doctrine2: explicitly fetching without cache

Tags: zend-framework, caching, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine2.2.2 with Zend Framework1 and am currently working on an editing tool.
A user clicks a link to move someting "up" in the list, my action does its work, changes are made to teh database, i redirect but then the result, newly fetched from the database is still the old version.

I would figure it has to do with cache since i am not temporarily storing the object in the session or anything.

So the Question is: Is there a way to fetch something and tell Doctrine, not to use the cache for this specific request? Or is there a possibility to delete certain cache entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, take a look at http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html?highlight=cache#result-cache .

There is a query api to enable, disable, ... result cache for example, individuallty on each query; or globally.